# ADF-based application with Tomcat: cannot login in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat, authentication, oracle-adf

I'm supporting some project, built using `ADF (using JDeveloper 11.1.2.2.0)` and deployed to `Tomcat 7.0.28.`

There was an issue with `JSessionID:`
IT should be different before logging-in and after it. To solve this, in my method `validate()` (that is executed when user submits login form) I do the following:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ec.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
session = (HttpSession)ec.getSession(true);
//setting some special session attributes
ec.redirect("nextPage");
```

When I arrive to `nextPage` I can get session with special attributes set above and go further. Everything works good when I log-in from Firefox or Chrome.

But when I log-in using IE 8.0 and get redirected to `nextPage`, my code gets session without those special attributes and throws me back to login page.

Using Wireshark I've realized that when Firefox logs-in it sends POST request with user input (username/password), receives answer with new `JSessionID in SetCookie parameter`, sends another request with `Adf-Window-id` and receives answer, after that it is redirected to `nextPage`.

But for IE flow is different: on log-in IE sends `two POST request in a row` `(first with user input, second with Adf-Window-id)` and after that receives two answers, each with different `JSessionID`. It stores the last one and gets redirected to `nextPage`. Obviously, the last JSessionID belongs not to the session where I've set my special attributes.

I've already spent few days trying to solve this problem by digging configs and Google, with no success. All I can see - IE sometimes can log-in as expected (in this case two answers mentioned above are received in reverse order), but it happens seldem.

Maybe you have faced same problem and solved it? Or maybe I'm doing/expecting something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem described by implementing my own servlet.

After successful logon the necessary session attributes are set and the session is **not** invalidated. Then, user gets redirected into context of my own servlet, which saves all session attributes, invalidates the session, creates new one and restores old attributes. After that, this servlet redirects user further, where he should get after logon. Of course, there are some tricks for security.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you do cannot work. When you perform Java EE container managed authentication then you authenticate the user session. If you invalidate the session then the user authentication is gone as well. The only way this can work is if you use Basic Authentication, in which case the browser sends use credentials with each request.

Oracle WLS has a proprietary method for this that allows to renew the session ID without invalidating it. Similar seems to exist for Tomcat, see here: http://www.koelnerwasser.de/?p=11

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

The method from the link uses Tomcat's sessions (org.apache.catalina.Session) instead of HttpSession (javax.servlet.http.HttpSession), this way is not prefferable since HttpSessions are used everywhere in application being supported.

If my approach cannot work then I'm surprised why it works when I perform log-in using Firefox or Chrome.